# Psycopg2 is not executing the passing of a table name to query

Tags: python, string, parameter-passing, psycopg2, psql

I can't figure what is wrong. I was able to use this same format to pass the name of a column to delete, but when I try to pass the table name, it does not work.

The error is: psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "delete_9" does not exist.

```py
try: 
    #pass the table name to get the columns
    q = sql.SQL("SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = {};")
    cur.execute(q.format(sql.Identifier('table1')))
    columns = cur.fetchall()
                
except:
    print("does not pass the string table")
```

but this does work:

```
for i in range(len(columns)):
    col_name= columns[i][0]
  
    query = sql.SQL( "UPDATE table1 SET {} = NULL WHERE {} = X;")
   
    cur.execute(query.format(sql.Identifier(col_name),sql.Identifier(col_name)))
```

I am passing a tablename to fetch the columns from. Why does it think I am inputting columns?

Comment: If you print the exception instead of just swallowing it, the error message and stack trace would probably help you to diagnose the problem.

Comment: the error says:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stars\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_18680\1389549302.py", line 22, in <cell line: 19>
    cur.execute(q.format(sql.Identifier('delete_9')))
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "delete_9" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = "delete_9"...

This makes no sense since the delete_9 is the table name and not a column?

Comment: I think the issue is in the use of `sql.Identifier`, which is used for an identifier like the table name in, e.g., `SELECT * FROM {}`. But here you actually want a string, since I believe the `table_name` column in `information_schema.columns` contains strings. So you want something like `cur.execute("SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = %s;", "table1")`, I think.

Comment: The `{}` in `... table_name = {}`  is a data value not an identifier, so you need to change that out to `%s` per [Passing Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).